# How to find lines in a 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a **2D numpy array** and I want to **find boundary points of both horizontal and vertical lines**.

```
gray_img = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

desired_outcome = [ [[1,1],[10,1]],
                    [[1,2],[10,2]],
                    [[1,3],[2,3]], ...]
```

Here are the **lines I want to find**:

[image]
[image]

Later, I want to **remove the smaller lines** to keep only those with more than 2 points distance.

Comment: `np.diff` would be a step in the right direction. -- depending on whatever you really need it for (is this image processing?), you might want "connected components analysis" or run length encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vertical lines:

```
m = np.diff(gray_img, 1, 0) # get discrete difference along the 0-axis
m = np.argwhere(m != 0)     # get indices where value is not zero 
m = m[np.lexsort(m.T)]      # sort indices first 1-column then 0-column
m[::2,0] += 1               #
```

output:

```
[[ 1  1]
 [10  1]
 [ 1  2]
 [10  2]
 [ 1  3]
 [ 2  3]
 [ 1  4]
 [ 2  4]
 [ 1  5]
 [ 2  5]
 [ 6  5]
 [ 7  5]
 [ 1  6]
 [ 2  6]
 [ 6  6]
 [ 7  6]
 [ 1  7]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 6  7]
 [ 7  7]
 [ 6  8]
 [ 7  8]]
```

horizontal lines:

```
m = np.diff(gray_img, 1, 1, append=np.zeros((gray_img.shape[0], 1)))
m = np.argwhere(m != 0)
m[::2,1] += 1
```

output:

```
[[ 1  1]
 [ 1  7]
 [ 2  1]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 3  1]
 [ 3  2]
 [ 4  1]
 [ 4  2]
 [ 5  1]
 [ 5  2]
 [ 6  1]
 [ 6  2]
 [ 6  5]
 [ 6  8]
 [ 7  1]
 [ 7  2]
 [ 7  5]
 [ 7  8]
 [ 8  1]
 [ 8  2]
 [ 9  1]
 [ 9  2]
 [10  1]
 [10  2]]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I also used the distance between even and odd points, and argwhere to get the indices of the first points where the line lengths are greater than 2.

distance = m[1::2,:]-m[::2]
desired_lines = np.argwhere(distance[:,0] >= 2)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm for horizontal lines based on prefix sums:

```py
# Do a prefix sum to get the lengths of each line.
gray_cumsum = np.cumsum(gray_img / 255, axis=1)
gray_cumsum[:, 1:] = gray_cumsum[:, 1:] * (gray_cumsum[:, 1:] != gray_cumsum[:, :-1])
# Reindex all the points so each line starts at 1.
start_num = gray_cumsum.copy()
a = start_num[:,1:-1] != 0
b = start_num[:,:-2] == 0
c = start_num[:,2:] != 0
start_num[:,1:-1] = start_num[:,1:-1] * np.logical_and(np.logical_and(a, b), c)
start_num[:, -1] = 0
start_num = np.maximum.accumulate(start_num, axis=1)
gray_cumsum = np.maximum(gray_cumsum - start_num, 0)
# Detect only the ends of each line.
gray_cumsum[:,:-1] = gray_cumsum[:,:-1] * (gray_cumsum[:,1:] == 0)
# Get the starting and endings points of each line.
end_points = np.stack(gray_cumsum.nonzero(), axis=-1)
lengths = gray_cumsum[gray_cumsum.nonzero()]
start_points = end_points.copy()
start_points[:, 1] = start_points[:, 1] - lengths
print(start_points)
print(end_points)
```

Just change the indexing to get vertical lines.
You can use the lengths array to filter out which lines you want.

Comment: perhaps a `np.diff` would add clarity

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Collecting both Horizontal and Vertical lines, also I reduced some superfluous comparisons that I used in the first draft: when scanning there is one direction, thus only the right/bottom end coordinates have to be updated, while the left/top are constant, equal to the beginning of the scanning of the current line segment. There is still some superfluous code that can be compressed.

EDIT2: Added the final formatting of the list as in the question.

It finds and lists first the horizontal lines, if the vertical have to come first as in your example output, then just put the second traversal on top.

```
    import numpy as np
                
    gray_img = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0],
                                     [0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0],
                                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
                                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
                                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
                
    bounds = []
    a = gray_img

    #SCANNING HORIZONTAL LINES
    for y in range(0,a.shape[0]):
      print("\nY=",y)  
      found = False #set to True when scanning a line
      left_x, right_x = 0,0
      top_y = y; bottom_y = y
      if a[y,0]==255:
        top_y = min(top_y, y)
        bottom_y = max(bottom_y,y)     
        found = True
      for x in range(0,a.shape[1]): #
        #while x < len(a[1]) or x!==0 #...
         if a[y,x]==255 and not found: #first item
           found = True
           right_x = x
           left_x = x
           #right_x = max(right_x, x)     
           #left_x = x # min(left_x, x)
           print("START",top_y, bottom_y, left_x, right_x)
         else:
           if a[y,x]==255 and found: #running line       
             right_x = max(right_x, x)     
             #left_x = min(left_x, x)
             #print(top_y, bottom_y, left_x, right_x)
         if a[y,x]==0 and found: #end of a running line
            bounds.append([top_y, left_x, bottom_y, right_x])
            print(a[y,x],end=",")
            found = False
      if found: #end of a running line matches the end of the dimension/line
         bounds.append([top_y, left_x, bottom_y, right_x])
         print(a[y,x],end=",")
         found = False                                       
    print("\n")
    print(bounds)
    print(a.shape)
    #print(f"LEN= {a.shape[0])}, {a.shape[1])}")  
    
    #SCANNING VERTICAL LINES
    for x in range(0,a.shape[1]):
      print("\nY=",y)  
      found = False #set to True when scanning a line
      left_x, right_x = x,x
      top_y = 0; bottom_y = 0
      if a[0,x]==255:
        top_y = min(top_y, y)
        bottom_y = max(bottom_y,y)     
        found = True
      for y in range(0,a.shape[0]): #
        #while x < len(a[1]) or x!==0 #...
         if a[y,x]==255 and not found: #first item
           found = True
           #right_x = max(right_x, x)     
           bottom_y = y       
           top_y = y
           left_x = x # min(left_x, x)
           print("START",top_y, bottom_y, left_x, right_x)
         else:
           if a[y,x]==255 and found: #running line       
             bottom_y = y #max(right_x, x)     
             #top_y = min(left_x, x)
             #print(top_y, bottom_y, left_x, right_x)
         if a[y,x]==0 and found: #end of a running line
            bounds.append([top_y, left_x, bottom_y, right_x])
            print(a[y,x],end=",")
            found = False
      if found: #end of a running line matches the end of the dimension/line
         bounds.append([top_y, left_x, bottom_y, right_x])
         print(a[y,x],end=",")
         found = False                                       
    print("\n")
    print(bounds)
    print(a.shape)   

# [[1, 1, 1, 7], [2, 1, 2, 7], [3, 1, 3, 2], [4, 1, 4, 2], [5, 1, 5, 2], [6, 1, 6, 2], [6, 5, 6, 8], [7, 1, 7, 2], [7, 5, 7, 8], [8, 1, 8, 2], [9, 1, 9, 2], [10, 1, 10, 2], [1, 1, 10, 1], [1, 2, 10, 2], [1, 3, 2, 3], [1, 4, 2, 4], [1, 5, 2, 5], [6, 5, 7, 5], [1, 6, 2, 6], [6, 6, 7, 6], [1, 7, 2, 7], [6, 7, 7, 7], [6, 8, 7, 8]]
#(15, 9)

#This list has to be additionally traversed in order to form [ [[1,1][1,7]], [...]] e.g.:

fm = []
for i in bounds:
  #i=[1,1,1,7] etc.
  f = [[i[0],i[1]],[i[2],i[3]]]
  fm.append(f)

print(fm) 

[[[1, 1], [1, 7]], [[2, 1], [2, 7]], [[3, 1], [3, 2]], [[4, 1], [4, 2]], [[5, 1], [5, 2]], [[6, 1], [6, 2]], [[6, 5], [6, 8]], [[7, 1], [7, 2]], [[7, 5], [7, 8]], [[8, 1], [8, 2]], [[9, 1], [9, 2]], [[10, 1], [10, 2]], [[1, 1], [10, 1]], [[1, 2], [10, 2]], [[1, 3], [2, 3]], [[1, 4], [2, 4]], [[1, 5], [2, 5]], [[6, 5], [7, 5]], [[1, 6], [2, 6]], [[6, 6], [7, 6]], [[1, 7], [2, 7]], [[6, 7], [7, 7]], [[6, 8], [7, 8]]]
```

Then you may traverse the result list and compute that distance (or you mean the lenght of the lines) and transfer only the longer lines to another list.

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you want?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

a = a[a != 0]
list = a.tolist()
print(list)
```

Comment: I think he doesn't, this is a nice example of using this numpy technique, but it only counts the number of non zero elements,  the output of this seems o be: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255], len(a) = 38.

He asks about storing the boundary coordinates of the lines.